# Root directory path problems

Tags: php, html

I am working on a website for a client and I am using xampp to serve and work on locally.

The site is loading fine at localhost/site but the resources are not being found. The previous developer used absolute paths in the index.php to define resources like so:

```
<script href="/includes/javascript.js">
```

The site fails to load javascript.js because it looks at:

```
localhost/includes/javascript.js
```

When it NEEDS to be:

```
localhost/site/includes/javascript.js
```

index.php is located here:

```
localhost/site/index.php
```

It works fine on the client server. What am I missing here?

Comment: try <script href="/site/includes/javascript.js">

Answer (score 0):

A URL starting with `/` is always absolute, you need a relative path here. So use

```
<script href="includes/javascript.js">
```

in your `index.php` or all files located in `localhost/site` or use

```
<script href="/site/includes/javascript.js">
```

for use in all files.

Answer (score 0):

You have a two mistake use `src` not `href` and remove `/` from start. try like that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/javascript.js"></script>
```